# Errors loading scripts on prefabs from asset bundles

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm currently trying to set up my project to allow users to download mini games post release. Todo this I am trying to use asset bundles to facilitate this, one containing the new games scene and one containing the assets and DLLs for the scripts required. The problem I am having is that when I load the scene or a prefab from the bundle all the attached scripts are still there but a warning says "the associated script can not be loaded. please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script". Is there something obvious that I am missing or do asset bundles not work this way and I'm going to have to rebuild my scene on load?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the scripts in the asset bundles assigned as references from GameObjects like you normally would. You can only access scripts from asset bundles by loading them with reflection. Then you can programmatically attach them to GameObjects, etc. from there (for example, load the assembly, find your Type, then use AddComponent() on a GameObject with your new loaded type).

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scriptsinassetbundles.html.

But even if you were to overcome these hurdles, it won't work on Windows Phone and it's against the terms of service of Apple's store, so ...